# My page won't scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, footer

I'm trying to create a very basic site. It needs to have a header that's fixed to the top with nav buttons and a footer with social media anchors. The content should sit in a container div in the middle and should scroll up and down whilst at least the footer stays in place. At the moment I've used this:

CSS:

```
#header {
   font-size: 1em;
   background-color:#000000;
   height: 4em;
   width: 100%;
   padding-top: 2em;
   padding-bottom: 1em;
   padding-left: 10em;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   text-align: center;
   left: 0em;
}

#container {
   width: 1280px;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 1em auto;
   overflow:scroll;
}

#footer {
   text-align:center;
   color:#FFFFFF;
   font-size: 1em;
   background-color:#000000;
   height: 5em;
   width: 100%;
   padding-top: 2em;
   padding-bottom: 0.5em;
   bottom:0em;
   position:fixed;
}
```

All the html are standard `<div></div>` with no other operations involved. I've tried removing all position commands and use a variety of overflow options but nothing is allowing me to scroll. The Footer simply sits on top of everything and the container acts as it's overflow:hidden.

Comment: Is this what you want to do? http://jsbin.com/xexevine/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that your #content doesn't have enough content to trigger an overflow. Otherwise maybe you'd like the header to be fixed as well? Check this [demo](http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/efbafa716548780b3b71960d8fc18b17).

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt your CONTAINER have a width of 100% and a set ###px for the Height? 
If you dont have a sidebar that has a set size, the middle cannot scroll if it is set at 100% unless it is set at 100% of something else...

```
#container {
width: 100%;
height: 1280px;
margin: 1em auto;
overflow:scroll;
```